# alter query in mysql

Tags: mysql

i want to add a new column noOfTry in a table which already have some columns. the column data will be integer type and default value will be 0. i know i need to use alter query, just asking for the correct format of the query for this case

Comment: Or better look directly at the mysql page. They have an awesome thing called "documentation". I also never heard of such a strange thing before, but it really exists AND it helps! Strange world:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option would be

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN noOfTry INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table `database`.`table` 
   add column `noOfTry` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NULL after `column`;
```

where column is the column before the on you want to add if you want to add in the middle of the table but this is optional.